# Mapbox-gl Angular 4

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

I have this problem when trying to run my map component with mapbox-gl. I get this error message:

```
WDS] Warnings while compiling.
warnings @ client?ffdb:120
sock.onmessage @ socket.js:37
webpackJsonp.../../../../sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
webpackJsonp.../../../../sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
webpackJsonp.../../../../sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
wrapFn @ zone.js:1166
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1517
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1543
client?ffdb:126 ./src/assets/mapbox-gl/mapbox-gl.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find SourceMap 'mapbox-gl.js.map': Error: Can't resolve './mapbox-gl.js.map' in '/home/admin/ang-dev/src``/assets/mapbox-gl'
 @ ./src/app/index/map/mapenter code here.component.ts 11:0-67
 @ ./src/app/index/index.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I use Mapbox-gl version 0.22.1 locally and is imported through the assets folder.

Installing mapbox-gl through NPM is not an option, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

I should mention I use cli/version: 1.4.10.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use javascript libaries from the asset folder. Install them with npm, then reference them in [Typings](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#typescript-typings) or use this [angular wrapper component implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mapbox-gl).